# Terraform: merge maps of lists, combine and make unique

Tags: terraform

After hours and hours of trying this is a sort of last resort, so hopefully someone can help me out.
Because of an duplication issue when deploying the azurerm_role_assignment I want to create a unique object set.

Original variable output is;

```
+ variable = [
      + {
          + assignment_key  = "administrators-application"
          + assignment_name = "SG_IT_INFRA"
          + assignment_type = "Group"
          + hostpool        = "administrators-vd"
        },
      + {
          + assignment_key  = "administrators-desktop"
          + assignment_name = "SG_IT_INFRA"
          + assignment_type = "Group"
          + hostpool        = "administrators-vd"
        },
      + {
          + assignment_key  = "servicedesk-desktop"
          + assignment_name = "SG_IT_SERVICEDESK"
          + assignment_type = "Group"
          + hostpool        = "servicedesk-vd"
        },
      + {
          + assignment_key  = "servicedesk-desktop"
          + assignment_name = "SG_ROLE_SERVICEDESK"
          + assignment_type = "Group"
          + hostpool        = "servicedesk-vd"
        },
    ]
```

As you can see, the first and second object have duplicate values at assignment_name and hostpool.

I've tried to fix this with the following code

```
per_assignment_keys = distinct([for tag in local.per_assignment: tag["hostpool"]])
  
  # with duplicate values
  per_assignment_helper_map = merge([for key in local.per_assignment_keys:
                  {for tag in local.per_assignment:
                     key => tag["assignment_name"]... if tag["hostpool"] == key
                  }  
               ]...)
  # duplicates removed  
  per_assignment_sa_map = {for k,v in local.per_assignment_helper_map: k => distinct(v)}
```

This gave the following output

```
  + per_assignment_helper_map      = {
      + administrators-vd = [
          + "SG_IT_INFRA",
        ]
      + servicedesk-vd    = [
          + "SG_IT_SERVICEDESK",
          + "SG_ROLE_SERVICEDESK",
        ]
    }
```

Unfortunately it is now an list, this in unusable because I'm not able to use a list within the azurerm_role_assignment principal_id resource.

So I've tried to flatten the output, with the following code

```
  per_assignment_sa_final = flatten([

    for key, value in local.per_assignment_sa_map : [
      for vm in value : {
        hostpool  = key
        assignment_name = value
      }
    ]
  ])
```

The result then will be

```
 per_assignment_sa_final        = [
      + {
          + assignment_name = [
              + "SG_IT_INFRA",
            ]
          + hostpool        = "administrators-vd"
        },
      + {
          + assignment_name = [
              + "SG_IT_SERVICEDESK",
              + "SG_ROLE_SERVICEDESK",
            ]
          + hostpool        = "servicedesk-vd"
        },
      + {
          + assignment_name = [
              + "SG_IT_SERVICEDESK",
              + "SG_ROLE_SERVICEDESK",
            ]
          + hostpool        = "servicedesk-vd"
        },
```

Again a list and not sufficient, the result must look like something as follow, which of course may be a list of objects, but without duplicates;

```
per_assignment_helper_map  = 
              {hostpool = administrators-vd, 
               assignment_name = SG_IT_INFRA},
              {hostpool = servicedesk-vd, 
               assignment_name = SG_IT_SERVICEDESK},
              {hostpool = administrators-vd, 
               assignment_name = servicedesk-vd}
```

This should give the ability to use;

```
// Assign AVD role to scope and group
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "avd_jumphost_sa" {
  for_each = local.per_assignment_helper_map  
  scope              = azurerm_storage_account.avd_jumphost[each.value.hostpool].id
  role_definition_name = "Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor"
  principal_id       = data.azuread_group.avd_jumphost[each.value.assignment_name].id
}
```

Final Solution;

```
locals{
  per_assignment = flatten([

    for key, value in var.application_groups : [
      for assignment in value.assignments : {
        assignment_key  = key
        assignment_name = assignment.name
        assignment_type = assignment.assign_type
        hostpool        = value.hostpool
        unique_key      = "${value.hostpool}-${assignment.name}"
      }
    ]
  ])

per_assignment_zipmap = zipmap(local.per_assignment.*.unique_key, local.per_assignment)
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the structure to be what is described at the end of the question, but without duplicate keys in the object? If the input is a variable, then why not restructure that instead of with transformation code?

Comment: Indeed, it needs to be a list of object but without the duplicate described at the begin. This list of objects is used in a much larger code (600 lines) where the duplicate is needed for the assignment to a AVD application pool. Now I need it to assign RBAC roles for the storage accounts within the hostpools which cant be duplicate.

Comment: But the described desired structure at the end of the question is not a `list(object)`, nor does it contain the duplicate at the beginning of the question, but instead a different duplicate?

Comment: I've edited my post to give a better view of what I'm trying to do. There will also be a data resource for the principal_id but thats something I can fix when the duplicate object variable is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve that with [`zipmap`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/zipmap).

Considering that `local.val` is your input variable:

```
  my_zipmap = zipmap(local.val.*.assignment_name, local.val)
```

`zipmap()` takes two arguments, the first one would be your `keyslist`, which is in this case the list of `assignment_name` attributes gotten with the [splat expression](https://splat%20Expressions%20-%20Configuration%20Language%20%7C%20Terraform%20%7C%20HashiCorp%20Developer). Which would produce:

```
  + name = {
      + SG_IT_INFRA         = {
          + assignment_key  = "administrators-desktop"
          + assignment_name = "SG_IT_INFRA"
          + assignment_type = "Group"
          + hostpool        = "administrators-vd"
        }
      + SG_IT_SERVICEDESK   = {
          + assignment_key  = "servicedesk-desktop"
          + assignment_name = "SG_IT_SERVICEDESK"
          + assignment_type = "Group"
          + hostpool        = "servicedesk-vd"
        }
      + SG_ROLE_SERVICEDESK = {
          + assignment_key  = "servicedesk-desktop"
          + assignment_name = "SG_ROLE_SERVICEDESK"
          + assignment_type = "Group"
          + hostpool        = "servicedesk-vd"
        }
    }
```

Optionally, you may get rid of the other fields if you want (looking at your desired output):

```
per_assignment_helper_map = {
  for key, elm in local.my_zipmap : key => {
    assignment_name = elm.assignment_name,
    hostpool        = elm.hostpool
  }
}
```

The output:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + per_assignment_helper_map = {
      + SG_IT_INFRA         = {
          + assignment_name = "SG_IT_INFRA"
          + hostpool        = "administrators-vd"
        }
      + SG_IT_SERVICEDESK   = {
          + assignment_name = "SG_IT_SERVICEDESK"
          + hostpool        = "servicedesk-vd"
        }
      + SG_ROLE_SERVICEDESK = {
          + assignment_name = "SG_ROLE_SERVICEDESK"
          + hostpool        = "servicedesk-vd"
        }
    }
```

And then you can just use `for_each` with the created map:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "avd_jumphost_sa" {
  for_each             = local.per_assignment_helper_map
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.avd_jumphost[each.value.hostpool].id
  role_definition_name = "Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_group.avd_jumphost[each.value.assignment_name].id
}
```

Full example:

```
locals {
  val = [
    {
      assignment_key  = "administrators-application"
      assignment_name = "SG_IT_INFRA"
      assignment_type = "Group"
      hostpool        = "administrators-vd"
    },
    {
      assignment_key  = "administrators-desktop"
      assignment_name = "SG_IT_INFRA"
      assignment_type = "Group"
      hostpool        = "administrators-vd"
    },
    {
      assignment_key  = "servicedesk-desktop"
      assignment_name = "SG_IT_SERVICEDESK"
      assignment_type = "Group"
      hostpool        = "servicedesk-vd"
    },
    {
      assignment_key  = "servicedesk-desktop"
      assignment_name = "SG_ROLE_SERVICEDESK"
      assignment_type = "Group"
      hostpool        = "servicedesk-vd"
    },
  ]

  my_zipmap = zipmap(local.val.*.assignment_name, local.val)

  per_assignment_helper_map = {
    for key, elm in local.my_zipmap : key => {
      assignment_name = elm.assignment_name,
      hostpool        = elm.hostpool
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "avd_jumphost_sa" {
  for_each             = local.per_assignment_helper_map
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.avd_jumphost[each.value.hostpool].id
  role_definition_name = "Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_group.avd_jumphost[each.value.assignment_name].id
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! This was not the full solution, because it removes all SG_IT_INFRA keys, except one. If SG_IT_INFRA was also assigned to another hostpool this would cause a problem.

To solve this I added an extra key within the object list which combines hostpool and assignment_name, this creates a unique key which I've used within the zipmap. I've added the final solution to the OP